# Entity Framwork: Why is my entity's collection property empty with LazyLoadingEnabled = false?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, serialization, lazy-loading

Here is the context:

```
public partial class Estate
{
    public Estate()
    {            
    }    
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

}

public Estate GetEstate(int EstateId)
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return db.Estates.Find(EstateId);
    }
 }
```

when I call  GetEstate(estateId), the collection of photos is ALWAYS empty. can anyone help. thank u very much.

according to this documentation: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx, before serialization, I have to turn off Lazyloading. what did I miss?

Comment: Of course it is. If you turn of lazy loading that is the behavior you get. What else did you expect? You need to eager load the Photos now.

Comment: @PeterBons according to this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx, before serialization, I have to turn off Lazyloading. what did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You turned off the feature to load related items on demand, so yes it no longer loads related on demand. You need to do it manually now with eager loading.

I don't think you can eager load with Find so it would be something like

```
db.Estates.Include(e => e.Photos).FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == EstateId)
```

You will need Include (and using System.Data.Entity to get the nice version of Include) whenever you want to load additional related data in one go.